# Multiplication between two numbers

Tags: c, multiplication

I have an assignment to build a function that multiplies 2 integer numbers and without using * or '-'. I can only use '+' '/' and '%'.

I noticed a lot of people are using shifting methods but i cant use without because we didn't learn it yet.

And as much as I can do it without 1 while loop easily the trick is it's supposed to be in n log n or log n runtime efficiency.

No list no arrays either though I don't see any way of using them anyway.

Is there any possible way of doing it ???

Comment: This is easy with a single loop, iterate n times with n being the integer argument and add the double value to a double result variable on each iteration. This should be `O(n)` runtime

Comment: If either number is 0, the result will be 0. Otherwise, if one of the numbers is a double you can divide the other number by the reciprocal of the double.

Comment: Shifting method works only for numbers that are powers of two, and since he wants to multiply `float` by `int` I doubt it would be useful. I think iterating over n times (where n is your `int`) and summing your `float` numbers n times would be the most optimal solution.

Comment: Im sorry guys i misread the question, its only integers no float or double.

Comment: `a*b = (a%2 == 1 ? b : 0) + a/2 * b` with some care for sign handling.

Comment: @Ctx, Re "*This should be O(n) runtime*", I think N would is supposed to refer to the number of bits in the factors, not their magnitude. If that's the case, your solution is O(2^N), which far exceeds O(N log N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another quick and dirty solution without recursivity that complies with the OP's requirement:

```
int Multiply(int a, int b)
{
  int result = 0;
  while (b > 0)
  {
    if (b % 2 != 0)
      result += a;

    a += a;
    b /= 2;
  }
  return result;
}
```

It's basically the same algorithm as the one in chmike's answer.

I didn't bother about the complexity but it looks pretty much like some O(log n).

It's definitely not working with negative values for b, I leave fixing this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks you i will use that one :) hopefully will achieve the goal

Comment: Fixing it to handle negative integers will either require use of `-`, or require converting  the operands and running total to `unsigned int` and converting the return value back to `int` (which might not work as the conversion of `unsigned int` to `int` is implementation-defined for negative numbers).

Answer (score 5):

This algorithm is O(nlogn). Divide and conquere.

```
double Multiply(int n, double x) {
    if (n == 0) 
        return 0.0;
    if (n == 1)
        return x;
    double a = Multiply(n/2, x);
    if ((n%2) == 1)
        return x + a + a;
    return a + a;
}
```

Note: the code has not been tested. I can't compile C code on my iPad.

Comment: That's probably the answer the teacher wants to see: it uses /, + and % and it also works for the modified question where the `x` argument is `int`. The O(n log n) is also respected.

Comment: Recursion makes it all horribly inefficient, so O(whatever) is irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundin, It's relevant for two reasons: 1) Runtime complexity is a measure of how something scales. The algorithm's complexity would be relevant to evaluate if the algorithm is worth considering for use in an arbitrary precision library. Micro-optimizations such as a removing recursion comes later. 2) Because the OP/assignment imposed a requirement on the complexity.

Comment: Tail call optimization isn't possible. [clang -O3](https://godbolt.org/z/tgrYf9), [gcc -O3](https://godbolt.org/z/BTcVyp). That's **a lot** of code for something that could have been carried out with a single instruction. The function call overhead and stacking is the bottleneck. It is _not_ a micro optimization. Furthermore, the number of branches is another bottleneck on many systems, rather than the number of comparisons.

Comment: @Lundin this exercise is somewhat articicial anyway. In a real implementation multiplication (without using proper multiplication instructions) would be done with shifting and adding and a loop.

Comment: @Lundin, I didn't say anything about tail call optimization. /// Re "*The function call overhead and stacking is the bottleneck*", I agree. I didn't say it wasn't an optimization.

Comment: The fact that i cant use division in 1/x is as for her is that it doesnt always give the correct value and even made a function to tell the numbers which wrong result given through this method

int kefel(int x, int y)
{
 return (int)(x / (1.0 / y));
}

void main()
{
 int i, j;
 int count = 0, total = 0;

 for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
 {
  for (j = i + 1; j <= 1000; j++)
  {
   if (kefel(i, j) != i * j)
   {
    printf("{%d,%d}, ", i, j);
    count++;
   }
   total++;
  }
 }

 printf("\nOut of %d couples, %d gave wrong answer\n\n", total, count);

 system("pause");
}

Comment: @snnoo14, The truncation you added is at fault. It's really bad to truncate floating point numbers.

Comment: @ikegami The point is that it doesn't matter if this is whatever(_n_) for a certain large _n_, because the program will explode with stack overflow before it is done with the calculation. But it is true that you get the program to crash quicker with an efficient algorithm. Amateur programs crash after O(n) seconds, while leet hacker programs crash after O(log n) seconds, right?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment given by Ian Abbot, here 
is a *cheeky* way to achieve your goal:

```c
double Multiply(int n, double x) {
    if (n == 0) return 0.0;
    else return x / (1.0 / n);
}
```

Or, if you want a more succinct one-liner:

```c
double Multiply(int n, double x) { return n ? x / (1.0 / n) : 0.0; }
```

The one change (but, IMHO, a *significant* change) over Ian's 'answer' is that it is the `int` argument that is checked for zero, as this is far more reliable than trying to test a `double` (or `float`) for *exact* zero.

NOTE: The *original* question specified that the numbers were "integer and double," and I gave this answer accordingly.

Comment: Hey, this is same as multiplying  dividing a number at 1/x and i was told not to use that

Comment: @snnoo14 But you didn't tell *us* not to do that in your post!

Comment: @snnoo14 sorry, we are not here to solve your homework. We are here to give you help with what you ask. You asked a question, you got an answer to **that** question.

Comment: OK, assuming non-zero, *positive* arguments: `return exp(log(n) + log(x));` You can add checks for negative and zero, and then deal with those special cases.

Comment: Don't worry, the answer is still valid, since you can always cast an int to a double and then perform the calculation.

Comment: True i did not say that in the question but it is the same thing as multiplication so i thought its understood, i would still appreciate any help to solve the assignment please

Comment: @snnoo14 what's wrong with the other answer? It complies perfectly to your requirements

Comment: Re "*True i did not say that in the question but it is the same thing as multiplication*", Yes, it performs the same function as multiplication, and that's exactly what you asked for!!!

Comment: Yes but the teacher did not approve this kind of division because it is same as a*b operation. The point is to use a loop of + / and or %. I could have done that division and send it but it is not the intended way of doing it.

Comment: I did point out in my answer that it is *cheeky* - but it does do what you actually asked. But the answer from @chmike is almost certainly very close to (if not exactly) what you're looking for.

Comment: The fact that i cant use division in 1/x is as for her is that it doesnt always give the correct value and even made a function to tell the numbers which wrong result given through this method

int kefel(int x, int y)
{
 return (int)(x / (1.0 / y));
}

void main()
{
 int i, j;
 int count = 0, total = 0;

 for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
 {
  for (j = i + 1; j <= 1000; j++)
  {
   if (kefel(i, j) != i * j)
   {
    printf("{%d,%d}, ", i, j);
    count++;
   }
   total++;
  }
 }

 printf("\nOut of %d couples, %d gave wrong answer\n\n", total, count);

 system("pause");
}

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Jabberwocky's answer (which OP should totally accept), here are a couple of methods to handle negative numbers.

The first method cheats a little bit by using `-` before the main loop if needed to get the correct sign for the result:

```
int Multiply(int a, int b)
{
  int result = 0;
  if (b < 0)
    a = -a; /* Cheat! But at least its a unary operation. */
  while (b != 0)
  {
    if (b % 2 != 0)
      result += a;

    a += a;
    b /= 2;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The second method makes use of `unsigned int` to do 2's complement arithmetic. Technically, there is a slight problem with this because a correct negative result could be replaced by an implementation-defined result according to the C standard rules. It is not likely to be a problem on most implementations that represent signed integers in 2's complement anyway.

```
int Multiply(int a_, int b_)
{
  unsigned int a = a_;
  unsigned int b = b_;
  unsigned int result = 0;
  while (b != 0)
  {
    if (b % 2 != 0)
      result += a;

    a += a;
    b /= 2;
  }
  // N.B. negative result might be replaced with implementation-defined result!
  return (int)result;
}
```

---

Aside: Disregarding the handling of signed integers, this method of multiplication is also known as the [Russian peasant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#Russian_peasant_multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using bit-shifts and additions. It has much in common with some of the other answers, but uses bitwise operations where possible, and handles negative numbers slightly differently (it also avoids the "unary minus" that Ian Abbot has admitted may be a 'cheat'):

```c
int mult(int a, int b)
{
    int answer = 0;
    int minus = 0;
    if (a < 0) {
        minus ^= 1;
        a ^= -1; ++a; // Negate (without using *) - assuming 2s complement representation ...
    }
    if (b < 0) {
        minus ^= 1;
        b ^= -1; ++b; // ... where "-x" is the BIT INVERSE of "x" PLUS ONE
    }
    while (a) {
        if (a & 1) answer += b; // If the nth bit of "a" is set we add "b << n"
        b <<= 1; // But shift up (multiply by 2)
        a >>= 1; // Bit shift down (divide by 2)
    }
    if (minus) { // ONE (and only ONE) number was negative ...
        answer ^= -1; ++answer; // ... so we negate our answer!
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This will work with negative numbers (one or both) but will *not* handle integer overflow (but, the native `z = x * y` won't do that, either).

Please feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.